# Action Cable not working in Safari on IOS

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, websocket, safari, actioncable

I want to exchange information about action cable in rails 6.0.2.

*On my desktop this also works great.*

But unfortunately in Safari on my IPhone and IPad (IOS 13.4) the connection to the websocket is not established. Neither the 'connected' nor the 'received' function is called.  I have no errors or infos in the Developer Tools console of Safari on my IPhone (connected via cable).

I have all relevant files here again, they are mostly standard generated by rails.

**app/javascript/channels/test_channel.js**

```js
import consumer from "./consumer"
consumer.subscriptions.create("TestChannel", {
  connected() {
    console.log("connected")
  },

  disconnected() {
    console.log("disconnected")
  },

  received(data) {
    console.log("received")
  }
});
```

**app/javascript/channels/consumer.js**

```js
import { createConsumer } from "@rails/actioncable"

export default createConsumer()
```

**app/javascript/channels/index.js**

```js
const channels = require.context('.', true, /_channel\.js$/)
channels.keys().forEach(channels)
```

**app/javascript/channels/index.js**

```js
const channels = require.context('.', true, /_channel\.js$/)
channels.keys().forEach(channels)
```

**app/javascript/packs/application.js**

```js
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
}
```

**app/channels/test_channel.rb**

```rb
class TestChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "some_channel"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

**ngnix Config**   (It does not work locally in development either)

```
....

location /cable {
  passenger_app_group_name test_app_action_cable;
  passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it was my mistake. In my Safari the experimental features 'NSURLSession WebSocket' was enabled. After I disabled the option, it worked. The option can be found at:

**Launch Settings > Scroll down to find Safari, and tap it. > Scroll down to click the Advance option. Then you will see the Experimental Features > Tap it**

[image: Experimental Features]